# Error when adding array to datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello i have a datagrid in my project and i have the following error:

```
warning: unable to bind to property 'name' on class 'Array' (class is not an IEventDispatcher)
```

Here is where i assign the data:

```
var myarr:Array = [];
packageData = packageData=SharedObject.getLocal("local_data");
for (var packageId:String in packageData.data.packages) {
    myarr.push(packageData.data.packages[packageId])
}

cur_uploads = new ArrayCollection(myarr);
dg_uploads.dataProvider = cur_uploads;
```

Ive read that i should use a `proxyObject` but i cant convert my `Array` to an `Object`. So is there any other solution to get rid of the error?

Comment: this is just an warning, it's not an error. Is the data added to the datagrid or your datagrid is empty ?

Comment: it is added, but its annoying to see it in the console

Comment: I get this all the times! I say do not worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do :

```
   var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
   packageData = SharedObject.getLocal("local_data");

   for (var packageId:String in packageData.data.packages) {
       arrayCollection.addItem(new ObjectProxy(
            packageData.data.packages[packageId]
       ));
   }

   dg_uploads.dataProvider = arrayCollection;
```